# Apple ID Sign In

Tags: iphone, apple-id

This morning when I clicked on my iPhone 6 the screen showed several messages.  One of them was:

> Apple Sign In Requested.  Your Apple ID is being used to sign in to a
>   device near Jinan, Shandong.

I have no idea what to do or if I've been hacked or not. Can someone explain what this means and can I log onto my iPhone and iPad?

I am typing this on a Desktop computer as I am afraid to open my iPhone.

Answer (score 1):

You can login into your account and check the devices which all are connected with your apple id , from that if you find anything strange you may please remove that device from the list. Then change your password of apple credentials. Use this [link](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT205064) for more reference and login.

Also it might be a good moment to enable Two Factor Authentication for your Apple ID on https://appleid.apple.com/.